# Creating Stripe customer from Stripe Token using .Net client library & Stripe.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I have a screen in my ASP.NET MVC web application in which I ask the user for their credit card information. They type it in.

Adhering to PCI guidelines, I am using Stripe.js to send this credit card information to stripe and get back a stripe token.

I then post this stripe token to my ASP.NET MVC application. In the application, I would like to create a customer. I would *not* like to charge the customer just now. I simply want to create a customer so I can charge them later using their Stripe `customerId`.

The documentation [provided here](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#creating-a-customer) makes it look simple. However, the client library that I am using (`Stripe` NuGet package version 1.12.0) does not offer the `StripeCustomerCreateOptions` class and many other classes mentioned in that document.

Instead, it has these two methods that help you create a customer:

```
public StripeObject CreateCustomer(ICreditCard card = null, 
             string coupon = null, 
             string email = null, 
             string description = null, 
             string plan = null, 
             DateTimeOffset? trialEnd = default(DateTimeOffset?));

public StripeObject CreateCustomerToken(string customerId);
```

As you can see, none of the methods are of any help to me. The first one requires the server to pass credit card information, which I am not doing as it is against PCI guidelines.

The second one assumes that you already have a customer and you want a token for the customer to use someplace else.

How do I create a customer from within my ASP.NET MVC application if I already have a credit card token for him that I got from Stripe.js?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/nberardi/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/CreditCardToken.cs#L8), you should be able to pass the token ID in the `card` parameter of the `CreateCustomer()` method.

Comment: @Ywain You are right. I looked things up in reflector. Turns out that there is a class named `CreditCardToken` that implements the `ICreditCard` interface and so it can be passed in place of the `card` parameter. The `CreditCardToken` class represents such a token and can be instantiated by giving to its ctor the `string` token you received from Stripe. I was able to do this immediately after writing the question. Just didn't have the time to update this question with an answer. If you will, I will mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a `CreditCardToken` from a token ID (see here: https://github.com/nberardi/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/CreditCardToken.cs#L8).

As `CreditCardToken` implements `ICreditCard`, you can then use it as the `card` parameter in the `CreateCustomer()` method.